Remove old commit from github repo
I committed and pushed an access token that I removed later and pushed, but the old commit is there and whoever checks that commit can see it. How can I remove an old commit from the remote repository and what effect would that have?

Refer this tutorial to delete the commit
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6oBzXWxa8Q

This answer is not helpful for future readers when the linked video is taken down. Please provide all relevant content in your answer directly.
